# Filter on different fields on array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

In Elasticsearch, say I have the document like this:

```
{
  "id": "testId",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "status": "STARTED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "STARTED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "ENDED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-06-11T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I wanted to filter all the documents such that I would get all the documents with status as ENDED and lastUpdatedTime should be highest in the input array. Eg. in above case, it will return this document as 2020-06-11T00:00:00.000Z > 2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z and 2020-05-11T00:00:00.000Z and status is ENDED. But say, for below document, it won't return:

```
{
  "id": "testId2",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "status": "STARTED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "STARTED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "ENDED",
      "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is because in this document STARTED has the largest lastUpdatedTime. How can I do this kind of filtering in Elasticsearch easily or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

**By this, below query you will get the result such that `lastUpdatedTime` should be highest in the input array corresponding to the `STATUS="ENDED"`**

**But this just solves only 1 part of your answer, the same query will not give you the desired result (i.e will not work for your second case where highest value of `lastUpdatedTime` is for `STARTED`)**

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "inputs": {
        "type": "nested"
      },
      "lastUpdatedTime": { "type": "date" }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "inputs",
      "query": {
        "match": {"inputs.status":"ENDED"}
      },

      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": [
    {
      "lastUpdatedTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
      } 

    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"inner_hits": {
      "inputs": {
        "hits": {
          "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
          },
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "my_index",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_id": "-s2KpnIBXf9A6l_vBbmP",
              "_nested": {
                "field": "inputs",
                "offset": 2
              },
              "_score": null,
              "_source": {
                "status": "ENDED",
                "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-05-11T00:00:00.000Z"
              },
              "sort": [
                -9223372036854775808
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```